# SharePoint look and feel upgrade

Tags: 2013, 2010, migration, upgrade

I need to upgrade the look and feel of my migrated site collection (from 2010 to 2013).

However, we have several thousand sites within the collection and the first attempt and upgrading the look and feel was slow. It ran for 4 days (it was stopped at this point).

Is there any way to perform this upgrade quicker or perform the upgrade at a site-level (rather than site collection)?

Thanks

Comment: Is given information helps you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a site collection level feature so you can not do it on site-level.

> **Site Collection Upgrade:**
>
> One the benefits of upgrading to SharePoint 2013 is that it all
>   happens behind the scenes. This means that your site collection
>   administrators can upgrade the look and feel – not to mention, handle
>   the change management – on their own timetable. There’s no additional
>   need for IT or server access, because admins can perform all of these
>   tasks.
>
> To upgrade site collections in from 2010 to 2013, follow these steps.
>
> 1. Run a health check to verify the site is ready to upgrade. On the **Site Settings** page for the site collection, in the **Site Collection Administration** section, click **Site collection health
>      checks**
> 2. Optionally (but cool), you can request an evaluation site collection (demo upgrade) – It’s heavy and it’s done by a timer job at
>      1 a.m.
> 3. Run a site collection upgrade. On the Site Settings page for the site collection, in the Site Collection Administration section, click
>      Site Collection Upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. How do you perform No.2?

Comment: This can be done through the pink bar at the top of the page or through Site Actions -> Site Settings -> under Site Collection Administration is Site Collection Upgrade. From here, we want to click **“Try a demo upgrade”** and another window pops up to create the demo or preview site.

Comment: Please check it here...http://blog.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2013-evaluation-site-collections/#.VznkMOTCdZY

Comment: is that fine for you?